# asp.net 301 redirect without ms visual studio

Tags: asp.net

I have a website (asp.net c#), dns for 2 domains are pointed to the same server. For one domain website display correct, but for second one, it shows IIS7 splash page...

www.mydomain.com - works fine
www.mydomain.co.uk - IIS7 splas page

How to make 301 redirect so i could point not working domain to working domain or add second domain to website settings to display website content.

I don't have MS Visual Studio, i'm using other editor to edit files, so which file i need to edit?

Comment: just add the binding for `www.mydomain.co.uk` to `www.mydomain.com`. on how to add a binding in IIS 7 http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731692(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: I disagree, that's bad for SEO and can confuse users. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

As @Furqan mentioned, you can add another domain binding to your website, but as far as visitors to your site (and search engines like Google) are concerned there now exists two websites with identical content. That's not good.

Install the "URL Rewriter" add-in for IIS: http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite

In IIS, add the second domain name to your bindings (don't forget the non-www version, so you should have four bindings:

```
mydomain.com
www.mydomain.com
mydomain.co.uk
www.mydomain.co.uk
```

Then you need to set-up a "Canonical Domain" rule that will redirect every visitor to a single domain name version of your site. In IIS Manager go to your website and open "URL Rewriting", then click "Add New Rule" and choose "Canonical...", then choose the canonical domain for your website, click Finish and you're all set.

Now, any visitors to your site from www.mydomain.co.uk or mydomain.com will be redirected to www.mydomain.com